# Why Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection not recognized

Tags: powershell

I was trying Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection by doing

```
.\Convert-BinaryToString
Convert-BinaryToString C:\file.exe
$InputString="base64string"
$PEBytes=[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($InputString)
```

But when I run

```
Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection -PEBytes $PEBytes
```

I get

```
Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection : The term 'Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection -PEBytes $PEBytes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [part of PowerSploit](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerSploit/3.0.0.0), which you need to install:

```
Install-Module -Name PowerSploit
```

If you've already installed it, you need to import it into your scope using

```
Import-Module PowerSploit
```

If you need it regularly, add the above in your [`$profile` script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7).